# Backbone & Rails. Why do you set routes in backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

js and I want to create a rails app with backbone. The only problem is, I cant seem to figure out what goes in the backend and what goes in the frontend. The approach I am using is to use rails essentially as an API.

I am looking at various different approaches and I cant seem to quite understand why you route in backbone as well as using normal rails routing.

My theory is:
You use rails to display initial html pages, and you use backbone routing to route the javascript files to that html pages so you can perform DOM manipulation there.

Here is the part of my code where I got that idea from. (NOTE: this is all mainly taken from Ryan Bates railcast on backbone.js)

backbone router

```
class Poster.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        '':'index'
        'posts/:id': 'show'

    initialize: ->
        @collection = new Poster.Collections.Posts()
        @collection.fetch({reset: true})


    index: ->
        view = new Poster.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
        $('#index_container').html(view.render().el)
```

views/main/index.html.erb

```
<div id="index_container"></div>
```

So does this backbone routing essential do the equivalent of just loading the javascript in the `index:` method at the top of the `views/main/index.html.erb`? (i know actually copying those javascript lines into the index.html.erb file wont work, its just a conceptual question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone is designed to be used in *single-page applications*, therefore it has a little to do with Rails routing. All Rails has to do is land a .html page, and everything else is client's concern.
If you intend to use Rails as an API, then its routing does not matter at all. You can even keep Rails application and frontend on different servers. In this case all what Rails has to do is *process requests* from the client.

For example, you can build your client-side without any hard ties to a backend, they can be absolutely separated. You just make AJAX calls from a client, then server processes them and responds with JSON.

Also, Backbone does not "route the javascript files to that html pages". It just executes functions according to a hash "route: action". These are just plain JavaScript functions which already can "see" JavaScript working within the document.